# Chrome Apps have broken "Close Window" keyboard shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I've been developing a standalone Chrome App, and I noticed that I wasn't able to close the application window with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>. If I look in the menu, it shows up as just <kbd>w</kbd>, which doesn't actually close the window when pressed. Clicking it from the dropdown works as expected.

[image]

It does this for any other standalone app I install as well. Is this a bug in Chrome? Some obscure misconfigured setting?

If it is a bug, is there any workaround I can implement for my app?

Comment: It definitely looks like a bug, and as such this is not a good place to report it. Try reproducing it on a dev/Canary build, and then report it at https://crbug.com/

Comment: Thanks. This is now [Issue 419054](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=419054).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for filing the bug. It should be fixed now:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/46fb0298b42b459bbc085c4b965a9fa4996d3e7c

Comment: By "now", which milestone / release channel you mean?